# how C# executes Page_Load if we write more than one?

Tags: pageload

If I have following code in my aspx.cs page :

```
    protected void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {

    }
    protected void PAGE_LOAD(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }
    protected void PaGe_LoAD(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

C# is allowing me to create these methods on same place, as due to case sensitive nature these are **Distinguishable**... But how compiler then decides which One to execute in lieu of its real Page_Load ??

thanks !!

Comment: Are you sure the compiler will actually execute one in lieu of Page_Load?

Comment: yes..Liviu.. I have executed it.. can you tell how this calling takes place....??

Answer (score 0):

One property in the website configuration is AutoEventWireup. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx

The events signatures are wired up at run time not at compile time. So, it is not compiler magic.

A piece of code is executed to figure out which delegate to call for which event. That code seems to be case insensitive.

For a more in depth explanation of the above take a look here http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/17/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx the information might be old but I don't think it is outdated.

An approach you could take in figure out the exact code is http://aspnetresources.com/articles/event_handlers_in_global_asax which answers the same question for events handlers in global.asax.

Get reflector and happy digging.

Comment: You are welcome Umesh, if the answer was of helpful please mark it accordingly.